# How to made a checkbox checked onclick on select an option from drop down: JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have 2 radio box inputs that I want to check when I select an option from a select dropdown menu.

I have a select box as like this:

```
<div id="checkout-shipping-method-load">
    <select id="shipping-method">
        <option value="option1">1 twister ($14.99 + $6.99 S&H)</option>
        <option value="option2">1 twister ($14.99 + $6.99 S&H)</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

And radio boxes like:

```
 <input type="radio" class="radio" checked="checked" id="s_method_flatrate2_flatrate2" value="flatrate2_flatrate2" name="shipping_method">
 <input type="radio" class="radio" id="s_method_flatrate_flatrate" value="flatrate_flatrate" name="shipping_method">
```

How can I make the selected option equal the selected radio button?

For example, if the first option is selected, then the first radio box is checked, or vice-versa.

Comment: Hey it's not a checkbox. It's a radio button.

Comment: oh sorry its typo error just consider it as radio@Mr. Engineer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `checked="checked"` from radio button and try.

```
<div id="checkout-shipping-method-load">
    <select id="shipping-method">
          <option value="option1">1 twister ($14.99 + $6.99 S&H)</option>
          <option value="option2">1 twister ($14.99 + $6.99 S&H)</option>
    </select>
</div>


<input type="radio" class="radio" id="s_method_flatrate2_flatrate2" value="flatrate2_flatrate2" name="shipping_method">
<input type="radio" class="radio" id="s_method_flatrate_flatrate" value="flatrate_flatrate" name="shipping_method">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

$('#shipping-method').change(function(){
    var option= $('#shipping-method').val();
    if(option == 'option1') {
        $('#s_method_flatrate2_flatrate2').attr('checked',true);
    }
    if(option == 'option2') {
        $('#s_method_flatrate_flatrate').attr('checked',true);
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is very simple on using `jquery`,

```
$('#shipping-method').on('change', function(){
   var criteria = $(this).val(); // will give you selected option value
   if(criteria === 'Your Value')  // your condition here
   {
       $('#s_method_flatrate2_flatrate2').attr('checked',true); // checking the radio button
   }    
});
```

You can similarly add conditionals to choose your `radio` buttons

Comment: prop() should be used instead of attr()

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution based on positions of related elements:

```
$('#shipping-method').change(function(){
   var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
   $(".radio:eq("+ optionSelected.index() +")").prop("checked", true);
});
```

Try:
https://jsfiddle.net/nwk5fez9/

Answer (score 1):

I really like San Krish's solution, but for the sake of completeness, here's my answer (in plain JS):

I'm simply going to check for the `change` event on the select box, then set the corresponding **index** of the radio buttons.

```js
var select = document.getElementById("shipping-method"),
    rbs = document.getElementsByName("shipping_method");

select.addEventListener("change", function () {
  rbs[select.selectedIndex].checked = true;
});
```

```html
<div id="checkout-shipping-method-load">
  <select id="shipping-method">
    <option value="option1">1 twister ($14.99 + $6.99 S&H)</option>
    <option value="option2">1 twister ($14.99 + $6.99 S&H)</option>
  </select>
</div>

<input type="radio" class="radio" checked="checked" id="s_method_flatrate2_flatrate2" value="flatrate2_flatrate2" name="shipping_method">
<input type="radio" class="radio" id="s_method_flatrate_flatrate" value="flatrate_flatrate" name="shipping_method">
```

Please note, that if you use this, the indices of the options and radio buttons *must* correspond; it would be wise to add other checks in the event listener.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the checked property of the radio button using Jquery, like so:

**JQUERY:**

```
$('#shipping-method').change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() === "option1") {
    $('#flatrate').prop('checked', true);
  } else if ($(this).val() === "option2") {
    $('#flatrate2').prop('checked', true);
  } else {
    $('#flatrate2').prop('checked', false);
    $('#flatrate').prop('checked', false);
  }
});
```

**NOTES:**

- [Since JQuery 1.6, you should be using prop() and not attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr).
- I've also added a default "SELECT" option to your drop down (see
  below), with logic to unset both radio buttons if that default is
  selected.  This is not required, but I added it in case it's useful for you.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="checkout-shipping-method-load">
  <select id="shipping-method">
    <option value="">SELECT</option>
    <option value="option1">1 twister ($14.99 + $6.99 S&H)</option>
    <option value="option2">1 twister ($14.99 + $6.99 S&H)</option>
  </select>
</div>

<input type="radio" class="radio" id="flatrate2" value="flatrate2_flatrate2" name="shipping_method">Flat 2
<input type="radio" class="radio" id="flatrate" value="flatrate_flatrate" name="shipping_method">Flat 1
```

[JSFiddle Demo here.](https://jsfiddle.net/5qzph3po/)